# Reading and writing the TOC for a PDF

Tags: itext, tableofcontents

My requirement is to prefix a PDF generated by some other process with a single 'cover page'.

I've written a relatively simple Ant task to concatenate a list of PDF documents, and this works well, but the TOC is not preserved in the process. By TOC I mean ..

[image: Image showing both styles of Table of content]

Ideally, both TOCs would be preserved, and adjusted for their new offsets, but I can see no means of reading or writing the TOC (the left hand one) in the iText API. Can anyone?

M.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not provide your code. Usually the loss of features like outlines or form fields when manipulating a PDF is caused by use of the wrong iText classes or by incorrect use of the right ones. Bruno points you towards working examples in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the [book about iText](http://itextpdf.com/book) and in the context of this book, I've written an example that explains how to concatenate PDFs while preserving the bookmarks (aka the outline tree). You can find this example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141). As you can see, you need the `SimpleBookmark` object to extract the bookmarks from the existing documents. Make sure that you shift the page numbers, or your links will point at the wrong pages. Finally add the new `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to the `PdfCopy` object using the `setOutlines()` method.

Once again, we've found proof that reading documentation saves time ;-)

Comment: Bruno you glorious bastard! Thanks for writing iText and the authoritative book on it.