# How can i add table of contents to my pdf using pdfbox.

Tags: java, pdfbox, tableofcontents

i am new to the world of pdf manipulation and especially using a low level implementation like pdfbox. I am trying to generate a Table of contents page for my pdf. From what i follow iText seems to be an easier fit for this but it is expensive. I have looked into Boxable, pdfjet, pdfclown, pjx they are all great projects but few lack documentation and others are paid. Is there any free software with a decent documentation that i can use to create a table of contents page for my pdf.

-Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean "outlines" (that appear on the left in Adobe Reader) or a classic table of content like e.g. done with MS Word, but with links? (See the image in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759406/reading-and-writing-the-toc-for-a-pdf)). Regardless of your answer - PDFBox is indeed very low level when it comes to creating PDFs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I am trying to implement the classic table of contents (like the one in MS word, typically found in thesis papers and textbooks) through pdfbox. If you could, please suggest any other alternative for implementing this apart from iText or aspose, form my understanding they are paid and pretty expensive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea of other free products. Re: PDFBox, I could find out how it is done if I'd get my hands on a PDF that has such a ToC. But even then, you'll have to position each line yourself, go to the next page when needed, etc.